# SIGTRAP when starting electron on WSL2

Tags: npm, electron, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I followed various online steps in Github forums and blogs to install VcsXsrv so that I could run an electron app through WSL for development. But I have been stuck on the following error when running `yarn start`:

```
/home/me/dev/my-electron-app-2/node_modules/electron/dist/electron exited with signal SIGTRAP
```

Specs:

- AMD Radeon R9 380 Series
- Windows 10 Pro Build 19044.1826 (3/23/21)
- VcsXsrv installed (1.20.14.0)
- WSL2 (latest) for Ubuntu 18.04

Dev Setup:

- Node 16.15.0
- Npm 8.5.5

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "My Desktop App",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "compromise": "^13.11.1",
    "compromise-numbers": "^1.3.0",
    "compromise-sentences": "^0.3.0",
    "electron": "^19.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-packager": "^15.2.0"
  }
}
```

Steps Tried:

- Updating from Electron 15 to 19
- Clearing package-lock.json
- Making sure VcsXsrv was not blocked by firewall (public/private)
- Updating WSL from 1 to 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did it I think was following this tutorial, specifically installing those missing libraries: https://www.beekeeperstudio.io/blog/building-electron-windows-ubuntu-wsl2

Incomplete list of libraries needed for electron/WSL Xserver usage:

- libnss3-dev
- libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev
- libgtk-3-dev
- libxss-dev
- libasound2
- libgconf-2-4
- libatk1.0-0

Related questions that were useful:

- General setup: [How to set up working X11 forwarding on WSL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61110603/how-to-set-up-working-x11-forwarding-on-wsl2?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- Similar fault: [Electron not starting properly due to SIGTRAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70060941/electron-not-starting-properly-due-to-sigtrap)
- Another similar fault: [Electron in Docker: SIGTRAP, ELIFECYCLE, errno1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66607726/electron-in-docker-sigtrap-elifecycle-errno1)
- WSL issue: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6430
- Another setup guide: https://gist.github.com/caseywatts/9700b402b6b51d1d6af9f0b206739770